# Why does os.StartProcess in Go set the child's process group id equal to the child pid

Tags: go, exec, fork, pid, process-group

The golang library function `os.StartProcess()` calls `setpgid(0,0)` in the child process after forking.

It does this on the "linux" and "bsd" configurations, sources here:
http://golang.org/src/pkg/syscall/exec_bsd.go?h=SYS_SETPGID#L105
http://golang.org/src/pkg/syscall/exec_linux.go?h=SYS_SETPGID#L117

I noticed in the past that the OSX Foundation library `NSTask - (void)launch` method does the same thing (undocumented). At that time it seemed like an annoyance as it makes it harder to manage trees of processes.

What is the benefit of these libraries doing this automatically?

Comment: Please consider asking this question on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) -- SO is not frequented by hard-core Go devs, unfortunately, so you might have better luck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it doesn't. It only changes the group if attr.Sys.Setpgid is true. This is to have feature parity with the system's API. It is not even an option on all OSes